# How to call a script source url from within an external file

Tags: javascript, html, file, external

I have a load of different projects and pages that use the same token for my google maps

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_TOKEN}&callback=init&v=weekly" defer ></script>`

However, instead of placing this in the footer of all my required pages, id like to be able to refer to an external file, whether it be a text doc or a .js file etc to be in once central place. Any help guys?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing yet. Basically I'm going to have 100's of different html pages that have the google maps api url with my token in. Just wondering if I could store that on an external file in one location rather than on each individual page.